# Trying to use controls in my repeater control (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a repeater control in my application and I want it to have other controls in it like a linkbutton (to allow people to make comment to the item) another linkbutton (that show the item and to be clickable so that I can redirect it to another page). All my attempt to code it in the code behind was denied. I can't find them in the code behind. Note: All these linkbuttons are rapped with a panel control in the repeater.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your controls in ItemCreated or ItemDataBound.

```
void Repeater_ItemCreated(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
   var control = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("yourLinkButtonId");
}

Or


void Repeater_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType ==     ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
      {
          var control = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("yourLinkButtonId");
      }
   }
```